# React Native + Android: Release build "Could not get BatchedBridge"?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to prepare my app for release, but when I run `adb install android/app/app-release.apk` or download my Beta build from the app store, it complains about with `Unfortunately App, has stopped`

I ran `adb logcat` and I see this:

```
01-13 22:46:03.949 13326 13351 E         : Unable to load script from assets: index.android.bundle
01-13 22:46:03.954 13326 13371 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
01-13 22:46:03.954 13326 13371 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.potatolabs.banana, PID: 13326
01-13 22:46:03.954 13326 13371 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
01-13 22:46:03.954 13326 13371 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
01-13 22:46:03.954 13326 13371 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:158)
```

Is this because my release build is trying to run in debug mode?? I thought it would only show that error if it's still trying to look for localhost:8081.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I had to run `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` first

Notes:
releasing android builds 1) `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` 2) build > generate signed APK 3) connect your phone 4) run `adb install android/app/app-release.apk` to test that the release build works on a device 5) run `adb logcat` to view the log in case anything is broken

Comment: Not load assets, any idea?